# java URI illegal charset |

Tags: java, string, character, uri

```
String s = "http://superserver.superdomen/controller.php?sq=1&query=ert|dfg=gdf|asd=dsa"

URI urs = URI(s);
```

> urs not created, illegal charset "|" , mnemonics not allowed in TZ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use  `URLEncoder.encode()`

```
String s = "http://superserver.superdomen/controller.php?sq=1&query="+URLEncoder.encode("ert|dfg=gdf|asd=dsa","UTF-8");
```

*Note:* Don't `encode` the whole url as it will also encode the `//` from `http://`

Answer (score 1):

Encode your URL. Replace `|` with `%7C`

```
String s = 
  "http://superserver.superdomen/controller.php?sq=1&query=ert%7Cdfg=gdf%7Casd=dsa";
```

### See also:

[URL Encoding](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp)